# Background changes color when hovering

Tags: zk, zk-grid

So I have a grid in Zkoss with a certain amount of columns. One the first row I place two labels which fill the first two columns (as expected).

I've written their style so that they don't have change color when you hover the mouse over them however one of the columns label is much bigger than the other and when I hover the mouse over the smaller label the area around which isn't filled by the text goes to white.

[ZKFiddle example](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1p0i1mc/45-My-issue)

I'm going insane around this as I'm simply unable of making that area have the same background as the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I already said in your duplicated question.

CSS is responsible and you just need to search with developer tools.

[This update to your fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1p0i1mc/46-My-issue) tooks me 2 min.

The changed thing :

```
.z-row:hover > .z-row-inner, .z-row:hover > .z-cell {background:red; !important}
```

Comment: I had tried to identify what was responsible for the white part but couldn't.                                       If my reading of what you changed is correct it should be read like this: when z-row:hover then z-row-inner and z-cell should have a red background right because they're children of z-row correct?

Comment: Indeed. It's just taken from the fiddle and selected the white area. Then you can see the CSS classes responsible.

Comment: My problem was that in chromium it didn't show the white area style when in hover. Thanks a lot